# How to get security question answer in .net sql membership provider?

Tags: .net, forms-authentication, membership-provider, security

Is there any way to get form code level security question answer in .net SQL Membership Provider? I'm struggling with allowing user to have change password reset and change features using the same provider.
Do anybody knows how to do that? Or if I would like to use question and answer feature it means that I automatically have to use security question to change password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MembershipProviders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) such as [SqlMemberShipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx) aren't designed to allow you to retrieve the password answer, only validate it. The method to validate the answer is [ResetPassword()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.resetpassword.aspx).