# Retrieve asp.net membership security answer

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-membership

This question was discussed many times. Most of them(99.99%) said no way.

[Asp.net Membership-How to match security answer explicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897625/asp-net-membership-how-to-match-security-answer-explicitly)

[MembershipProvider.GetPassword algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323800/membershipprovider-getpassword-algorithm)

[How to get security question answer in .net sql membership provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308068/how-to-get-security-question-answer-in-net-sql-membership-provider)

However there is an answer say yes.

http://throughexperience.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-retrieve-memberships.html

So I am confused. Which one is right?

Comment: Why don't you just try the last link there?  If it works, you know the answer to your question.

Comment: I tried it never success. I wonder why?

Comment: Exactly,  the code is pretty straight forward.  In a short time you should know if it will do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last article clearly states that you can dencrypt password answer only if it is stored as 'Encrypted' or 'Clear'.

In other words, it doesn't work if passwords (and password answers) are stored as 'Hashed'.

By default, passwordFormat is 'Hashed' unless you explicity mentions it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.passwordformat.aspx

Note: If your password are stored as 'Encrypted', please make sure you use the same machine key to decrypt it.